# Django form fields as template variables

Tags: django, forms, templates

The main question is if it is possible to specifify specific form fields at different given locations in your html template in any smooth way. e.g. {{ form.password }} However, that does not seem to work. (I swear that I have seen this somewhere, but I just can't find it anymore on the internet)

My view for signing up new users is inheriting from UserCreationForm and looks kind of like this:

views.py

```
def signup(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
        raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=raw_password)
        login(request, user)
        return redirect('home')

else:
    form = UserCreationForm()
return render(request, 'core/authentication/registration_form.html', {'form': form})
```

It sends this form straight to the template registration_form.html, this is how I wish it worked:

```
<form class="form" method="POST" action="">
    <div class="card-body">
        <div class="input-group form-group-no-border">
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <i class="now-ui-icons users_circle-08"></i>
            </span>
            {{ form.first_name }}
       </div>
    </div>
```

This is how it actually works (for now):

```
<form class="form" method="POST" action="">
    <div class="card-body">
        <div class="input-group form-group-no-border">
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <i class="now-ui-icons users_circle-08"></i>
            </span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name...">
       </div>
    </div>
```

This might be a stupid question, but oh well I am curious.

Thank you in advance

Comment: It's possible to define individual fields, your first example is correct. And it's better to do it that way, not harcoding the field. You are inheriting from `UserCreationForm` with a form with the same name? Post your form code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If i've understood your question correctly, here is how django says you should render django form fields manually.

```
{{ form.non_field_errors }}  # here django renders errors which do not belong to any field
<div>
    {{ form.field_1.errors }}  # here django renders errors which belong to field_1
    {{ form.field_1.label_tag }}  # label element
    {{ form.field_1 }}  # input element
</div>

# some html

<div>
    {{ form.field_2.errors }}
    {{ form.field_2.label_tag }}
    {{ form.field_2}}
</div>
```

You can read this [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/) in the lower half.

Each field ( each label, input, error elements ) can be rendered with custom classes and widgets.

Comment: Oh yeah, I feel incredibly dumb at the moment haha.

Merry Christmas